# Converting transparent pngs Crashes SDL/OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, png, sdl, transparent

If I try to convert a transparent .png SDL_Surface to a OpenGL texture, then the moment the program tries to access any data from the SDL_Surface, it crashes. I observed other people's code involving transparent pngs, but they are the same and don't crash, according to other askers. This is my code, the part where the program crashes. It crashes at "n0fColors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel".

```
GLuint CONVERT_IMAGE(SDL_Surface * surface)
{
    GLuint texture;
    GLenum texture_format;
    GLint nOfColors;

    nOfColors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    if (nOfColors == 4)
    {
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            texture_format = GL_RGBA;
        else
            texture_format = GL_BGRA;
    }
    else if (nOfColors == 3)
    {
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
            texture_format = GL_RGB;
        else
            texture_format = GL_BGR;
    }

    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nOfColors, surface->w, surface->h, 0, texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels );

    delete surface;
    return texture;
};
```

EDIT: I should note that the transparent parts of the PNG is %100 transparent.
EDIT: This is my call to my images:

```
void image_init()
{
    wall_clay_0 = IMG_Load("images/walls/clay.png");

    walls_image.clay = CONVERT_IMAGE(wall_clay_0);
};
```

Comment: Check that surface and surface->format is not NULL pointers.

Comment: It returned NULL. None of the SDL_Surface not return null, even the non-transparent ones.

Comment: That means problem is in calling code, not in this function.

Comment: By the way, the same code work with bmps without crashing or any problems.

Comment: The images are not returning NULL, just the surface->format->bytesperpixels.

Comment: bytesperpixels can not be NULL. It is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I needed to make all my loaded images temporary surfaces, then make it equal to SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha of itself. For example:

```
SDL_Surface * surface;
surface = IMG_Load(bla.png);
surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(surface);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loading code should be like this:

```
void image_init()
{
    wall_clay_0 = IMG_Load("images/walls/clay.png");
    if (!wall_clay_0)
    {
        printf("Error loading mage: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
        abort(); // or whatever your application should do
    }
    walls_image.clay = CONVERT_IMAGE(wall_clay_0);
}
```

Comment: Well I understood you said surface is NULL. Be more specific what is what.

Comment: The surface loads fine, and is not null, but the surface->format is NULL though.